# Detect onHover (jquery or css) event with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a jquery/js script that will listen for an onHover event?

I'm building a listening library and we want to include the ability to help the website owner detect when a user initiates an onHover event - so they know it was taking the attention of their visitor/user.

[image]

Listen for onHoverStart (when they mouse on an element that has an onHover associated with it) & onHoverEnd (when they mouse away from the element).

Comment: You're looking for `onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave`

Comment: Indeed, in jQuery they are combined as `.hover()`. https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple example which works with **onmouseenter** and **onmouseleave** I modified from http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmouseover

When a user hovers the image gets bigger. When hovering stops the image returns to normal size. You can also customize the function to do what ever you want **onmouseenter** and **onmouseleave**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img onmouseover="WhenUserHovers(this)" onmouseout="WhenUserStopsHovering(this)" border="0" src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley" width="32" height="32">

<p>The function WhenUserHovers() is triggered when the user moves the mouse pointer over the image.</p>
<p>The function WhenUserStopsHovering() is triggered when the mouse pointer is moved out of the image.</p>

<script>
function WhenUserHovers(x) {
    x.style.height = "64px";
    x.style.width = "64px";
}

function WhenUserStopsHovering(x) {
    x.style.height = "32px";
    x.style.width = "32px";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Also you can make use of jQuery (a javascript library) **mouseenter** and **mouseleave** http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_mouseenter_mouseleave

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").mouseenter(function(){
        $("p").css("background-color", "yellow");
    });
    $("p").mouseleave(function(){
        $("p").css("background-color", "lightgray");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Move the mouse pointer over this paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Or jQuery's **mouseover** and **mouseout** http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_mouseover_mouseout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").mouseover(function(){
        $("p").css("background-color", "yellow");
    });
    $("p").mouseout(function(){
        $("p").css("background-color", "lightgray");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Move the mouse pointer over this paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

The difference between jQuery's **mouseenter/mouseleave** and **mouseover/mouseout** is **mouseenter** works when the mouse pointer enters the selected element while **mouseover** works when the pointer enters the element or any child elements of the element.

Answer (score 0):

to detect the hover with jquery use this

```
$("selector").hover(function(){
//do something when it is hover
},function(){
//do something when you lose hover
});
```

you can read more about this here https://api.jquery.com/hover/